# Aggregating daily to weekly given an array of week dates

Tags: r, date, time-series

Before I start, let me say I am aware various definitions of week exist, but I am curious as to how to solve this problem without knowing the definition of the week used in my dataset.

I want to sum daily values into weekly values. I have a vector of dates which represent the end of the week (saying `week`), and a data.table with daily frequency dates (saying `dt`). I need to search up each date in `week` and sum its corresponding value and the 6 before to come up with a new aggregated value. The transformed date should correspond to the same date as in `week`.

The time series has no gap.

**`week`**

```
["2017-01-01", "2017-01-08", ...]
```

`dt`

```
"date","value"
"2016-12-26",1
"2016-12-27",1
"2016-12-28",1
"2016-12-29",1
"2016-12-30",1
"2016-12-31",1
"2017-01-01",1
"2017-01-02",2
"2017-01-03",2
"2017-01-04",2
"2017-01-05",2
"2017-01-06",2
"2017-01-07",2
"2017-01-08",2
...
```

**`expected result`**

```
"2017-01-01",7
"2017-01-01",14
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the `week_starts` and do the sum of previous 6 days, i.e.

```
week_starts <- as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-08"))

df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
sums <- sapply(week_starts, \(i) sum(df$value[df$date >= (i - 6) & df$date <= i]))

cbind.data.frame(week_starts, sums)

  week_starts sums
1  2017-01-01    7
2  2017-01-08   14
```

**DATA**

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17161, 17162, 17163, 17164, 
17165, 17166, 17167, 17168, 17169, 17170, 17171, 17172, 17173, 
17174), class = "Date"), value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```